# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'Ea'

Tags: python, class

I am trying to implement an Arrhenius type law to compute a non-dimensional temperature dependent viscosity.

I want to iterate over both a series of activation energies (Ea) which is a parameter of the function - and non-dimensional temperature which is the independent variable.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

"""
    define class for Arrhenius viscosity law
    Langemeyer et. al.     Eta_T = b*exp((Ea/(temp +1)) - (Ea/2))
    Where   Eta_T ==> Temperature dependent Viscosity
            Ea    ==> Activation Energy
            t  ==> Non-dimensional temperature 
"""
class ArrVisc(object):
    def __init__(self, Ea):
        self.Ea = Ea
        
    def value(self, t):
        return np.exp((self.Ea/(t+1.))-(self.Ea/2.))
       
    
'''
    Define arrays for valid activation energies and non-dimensional 
    temperature
'''
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
Ea = [20.0, 23.03, 25.35, 29.96, 32.22]

'''   Initialize array for temperature dependent viscosity Eta_T '''

Eta_T = []

"""
    Iterate Class ArrVisc() over activation Ea[]
    and non-dimensional temperature
"""
for i in range(len(Ea)):
    visc = ArrVisc.value(t, Ea[i])
    Eta_T.append(visc)
```

Error Message:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'Ea'
```

Comment: As an FYI, I have a functional version of the code that uses a function "def ArrVisc()". I am trying to develop an understanding of using "class" to try and develop something more reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate your object first before trying to call the value method. I would suggest you change the definition of visc to the following:

```
visc = ArrVisc(Ea[i]).value(t)
```

Comment: That was a simple and elegant solution.. It worked!! Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object:

```
av = ArrVisc(Ea)
for i in ...:
    visc = av.value(t)
    Eta_T.append(visc)
```

Calling `ArrVisc.value(...)` directly is incorrect; normal methods are called on objects, not directly on the class. If you do have methods that should be called directly on the class, they should be marked `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` (and cannot access `self`, because there is no `self` in that situation).